# powershell better way to test if both directories exists or one only on all pc's from domain and output to csv

Tags: powershell, active-directory

could you please help me to correct this script (gathered by pieces from internet) or better change logic how it should work (not working currently). The goal is to get pc's where only one folder exist (oracle11) and not both (11+12) and export it to csv. Oracle is a real pain in the ....
Thank you in advance for your advice.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties * | Select -Property Name
$output = @()

#$computers = get-adcomputer -filter * | Select-Object -Expand Name | foreach-object {

Foreach ($Computer in $computers){
  if ( (test-path "\\$Computer\C$\oracle\product\11.2.0\" ) -and !( test-path "\\$Computer\C$\oracle\product\12.2.0" )) {
    $output += $Computer
  }
} 
$output | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path c:\temp\test.csv
```

Comment: What is it that needs correcting? Is the script not working? If so, how is it behaving? Throwing errors? Giving incorrect or inconsistent results? Please [add these details to your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70877487/edit) :)

Comment: it does not export a thing to csv, there is logical or construction error

Comment: That can probably be explained by the fact that you use `$Computers` (instead of `$Computer`) in the paths you construct :)

Comment: still empty result, should be something else :(, will correct this already in original post

Comment: Change `Select -Property Name` to `ForEach-Object -MemberName Name` and it'll likely work (assuming the account has read access to the `C$` shares on all the target machines)

Comment: Yes indeed, now it is running and on some pc/servers I get access denied (not an issue I think) but the script is far from done, would take a while (2.3k pc's...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the path strings you construct inside the loop are not as you expect.

When you pipe the output from `Get-ADComputer` to `Select-Object -Property Name`, it creates a new object with a single property `Name` for each input object.

When you then implicitly convert one of these objects to a string, the resulting value is going to be `"@{Name=Computer01}"`, instead of just `"Computer01"`.

You can observe this yourself, by calling `Write-Host` instead of `Test-Path`:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * |Select-Object -Property Name |ForEach-Object {
  Write-Host "\\$_\C$"
}
```

To extract just the value of the `Name` property from each ADComputer, use `ForEach-Object -MemberName` instead of `Select-Object -Property`:

```
$computerNames = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties * | ForEach-Object -MemberName
$output = @()

foreach($ComputerName in $computerNames){
  if ( (Test-Path "\\$ComputerName\C$\oracle\product\11.2.0\" ) -and !( Test-Path "\\$ComputerName\C$\oracle\product\12.2.0" )) {
    $output += $ComputerName
  }
} 
$output | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path c:\temp\test.csv
```

Note that passing `-Properties *` to `Get-ADComputer` is unnecessary, the object name is always part of the default property set sent back by the Get-AD* cmdlets.

Comment: script is still running, lol, do you think there is a way to make it multi stream? I'v also tried pdq inventory but if both of oracles were installed (registry,filesystem and so on) is full of garbage ....and i'm just failing to make a correct working filter to determine where only old v11 was installed...Thank you for you solution